# if does not work in changing color cell

Tags: if-statement, for-loop

After testing code below, all steps works except the if statement. Values of cells which are indeed "ik kom niet, mijn partner komt wel" >> but the color doesnot change into red.
Who is able to solve this problem?

```
function Changecolor (e)
{
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234");
    var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("lijst beschikbare bridgers");
    var rows = target_sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:K100");
    range.setBackground('');

    for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++)
    {  
        var value = target_sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
        if (value == "ik kom niet, mijn partner komt wel")
        {
            target_sheet.getRange(i,1).setBackground('red');
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikeng ths for editing. I will change all my scripts like this.
Problem is solved. Actually there was no problem the script is OK and works. I just gave the wrong range:

```
    var value = target_sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
```

should be:

```
    var value = target_sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
```

Such a stupidy costs me at least 3 hours...